# Probleb on Ajax Calling

Tags: javascript, ajax, windows, macos

I am making a simple ajax call, its working but the problem here is that 
when i am running it on MAC its only run on Safari, and when I run on windows 7/8 its only run on IE, codes are here

```
function check(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url="http://asdev-nfl.dtvce.com/CMPService/service/AuthorizationObjectService?siteId=Android_Customer_01&userName=bsstest03@att.net&password=widget03&environment=prod";
    // var url="http://10.23.181.154:8080/CMPService/service/AuthorizationObjectService?siteId=Android_Customer_01&userName=bsstest03@att.net&password=widget03&environment=prod";
    xhr.open("POST",url,true);
    console.log("inside function 1");
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        console.log("I am Inside ajax");
        if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200)
        {
            var resp = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(resp);
            alert("alerting response"+resp);
            document.getElementById("outPut").innerHTML=resp;
        }
        else{
            alert("there is a error"+xhr.readyStatus+"Ready Status "+xhr.status);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I think your `console.log()` calls might be the problem, as they do not work in all browsers. Have you gotten any Javascript errors?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://asdev-nfl.dtvce.com/CMPService/service/AuthorizationObjectService?siteId=Android_Customer_01&userName=bsstest03@att.net&password=widget03&environment=prod. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Thats what I am getting in Chrome
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://asdev-nfl.dtvce.com/CMPService/service/AuthorizationObjectService?siteId=Android_Customer_01&userName=bsstest03@att.net&password=widget03&environment=prod. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.